# BibTex, tugboat and citation formating

Tags: bibtex

I'm finishing an article but I'm having a little trouble with BibTex. I don't know how to get properly formatted citations. I've never used BibTeX. The layout is awful.
How do I adjust font size? How to adjust urls?

```
\documentclass{ltugboat}

\begin{document}
  \cite{ctan-elements}
  \cite{ctan-euclide}
  \cite{apollonius}    
  \cite{kissing}
  \cite{weisstein}
\bibliographystyle{tugboat}
\bibliography{tug_article}
\end{document}
```

My file tug_article.bib (I don't know if `howpublished` is better than `url`?)

```
@misc{ctan-elements,
        author = {Alain Matthes},
        title = {tkz-elements},
        howpublished =  "https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-elements",
        year = {2024},
}

@misc{ctan-euclide,
        author = {Alain Matthes},
        title = {tkz-euclide},
        howpublished =  "https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide",
        year = {2023},   
}

@misc{apollonius,
    author   = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    year = {n.d.},
    title    = {Apollonius Circle. {From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource}},
    howpublished =  "https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusCircle.html",
}

@misc{kissing,
    author   = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    year = {n.d.},
    title    = {Tangent Circles. {From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource}},
    howpublished =  "https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentCircles.html",
}

@misc{weisstein,
    author   = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
    title    = {Tree. {From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource}},
    url      = {\url{http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html}},
    note     = {Last visited on 13/4/2012},
}
```

The problem is the Underfull \hbox and the text that extends into the first lines of the citations.

[image]

Comment: I normally use the `url`  field in the bib for tugboat. Imho the style knows also the field `urlnewline = 1` which forces a newline (but that wasn't added by me, Karl must have done it, when reviewing).

Comment: `\raggedright` before the bibliography?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried `SetBibJustification{\raggedright}` but it was worse. With `\raggedright` the first line takes up the entire width and urls are not cut.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How do you use `urlnewline`? Where do you put it? In the end, my problem isn't so much with the URLs as with the fact that the text extends over the entire first line and sometimes over subsequent lines.

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries, I came up with this:

I used `\usepackage{url}` and wrote my tug_article.bib like this:

[image]

The result :

I would have preferred a line break for the beginning of the url, but if I proceed as I did, the url is cut out.

[image]

Comment: Consider also loading `xurl` instead of `url`.